# scala typing require implicit

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-implicits

I'm trying to build following

I have a parent generic class

```
abstract class ResultProvider[+T: Writes](db: DB) {
  def get(id: Long): Future[Seq[T]]
}
```

And some implementations, e.g.

```
class LengthProvider(db: DB) extends ResultProvider[LengthResult](db){
  override def get (userId: Long): Future[Seq[LengthResult]] = ...
}

object LengthProvider extends ((DB) => DisciplinePredictor) {
  override def apply(db: DB) = new LengthProvider(db)
}
```

I have following configuration map:

```
val providers: Map[String, ((DB) => ResultProvider[???])] = Map(
  "length" -> LengthProvider,
  "width"  -> WidthProvider,
   ...
)
```

My question is what should I put in place of ???. Ideally, it should be something like `T : Writes`, as I only care that this type has `Writes` implicit implemented, as I'm going to `Json.toJson` it. It will compile with `Any`, but then the information that the class should implement `Writes` implicit is lost.
Or should I use a different approach? I could probably create a superclass for all my result case classes (e.g.`LengthResult`), but I want to get away with the implicits.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar That's not what is wanted at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to write `ResultProvider[_]` (search for "existential types" if you are unfamiliar with this syntax), but you'll need to give a name to the implicit:

```
abstract class ResultProvider[+T](db: DB)(implicit val writes: Writes[T]) { ... }
```

Elsewhere:

```
val provider: ResultProvider[_] = providers("length")
import provider.writes // makes the implicit visible here
...
```

You might need to help the compiler  (or yourself, if you need to name the type) by providing a type variable:

```
providers("length") match {
  case provider: ResultProvider[a] =>
    import provider.writes 
    ...
}
```

Comment: It worked! Can you please elaborate why I need to help the compiler with a type variable (i.e. `a`)? It doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately, this depends on details of compiler's type inference which I don't understand. I've just been in similar situations before.