# scala implicit in function type definition

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-implicits

I have following abstract class:

```
abstract class FieldProvider[+T: Writes](db: DB)(implicit i: RequestAction, j: ExecutionContext) {}
```

and following implementations:

```
class LengthProvider extends FieldProvider ...

object LengthProvider extends ((DB) => LengthProvider) {
  def apply(v1: DB): LengthProvider = new LengthProvider(v1)
}

class WidthProvider extends FieldProvider ...

object WidthProvider extends ((DB) => WidthProvider) {
  def apply(v1: DB): WidthProvider = new WidthProvider(v1)
}
```

The reason why I have these `apply` methods is because I need following configuration map:

```
val providers: Map[String, ((DB) => FieldProvider)] = Map(
 "length" -> LengthProvider,
 "width"  -> WidthProvider
)
```

So that I can initialize the providers by the string containing their name:

```
providers("length")(db) // returns a new instance of LengthProvider
```

Now, my problem is that all these providers constructors require two implicit variables. But I don't know how to include it into the function definition `(DB) => FieldProvider`. So, essentially, the `apply` method signature should be something like `(DB)(implicit RequestAction, ExecutionContext) => FieldProvider`, but I don't know if there is a correct syntax for what I'm trying to do.

I could also give up and pass them explicitly:

```
object WidthProvider extends ((DB, RequestAction, ExecutionContext) => WidthProvider) {
   def apply(v1: DB, v2: RequestAction, v3: ExecutionContext): WidthProvider = new WidthProvider(v1)(v2,v3)
}
```

But then I'll have to pass them explicitly elsewhere, instead of `providers("length")(db)`, I'd have to write `providers("length")(db, implicitly[RequestAction], implicitly[ExecutionContext])`, which doesn't feel right.

Comment: You move the things that need the implicits to a lower scope, inside the `LengthProvider` implementation. Instead of having them as constructor arguments, you do a per method approach.

Comment: Well, this helped. Feel free to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala typing require implicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569881/scala-typing-require-implicit)

Comment: The underlying codebase is the same indeed, but the questions are different, and the solutions proposed are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume `FieldProvider` has 2 methods that need the implicits. The more convenient way to avoid duplication is to pass them as constructor level implicit arguments and then all the internal methods in `FieldProvider` can "share" them.

However, this won't help in your current class tree, so to fix this, instead of doing:

```
abstract class FieldProvider()(implicit param1: X1..) {
  def test: T = param1.doSomething
}
```

Simply move the implicit to method level such that you can provide it at a time different than extending the constructor.

```
abstract class FieldProvider() {
  def test()(implicit param1: X1): T = param1.doSomething
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, essentially, the `apply` method signature should be something like `(DB)(implicit RequestAction, ExecutionContext) => FieldProvider`, but I don't know if there is a correct syntax for what I'm trying to do.

Note that you might directly get (in a future  Scala 2017 version) an **[implicit function type](http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/12/07/implicit-function-types.html)**.

See [pull request 1775](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/1775), by [Odersky](https://github.com/odersky) himself.

> Let’s massage the definition of `f1` a bit by moving the last parameter section to the right of the equals sign:

```
def f1(x: Int) = { implicit thisTransaction: Transaction =>
  thisTransaction.println(s"first step: $x")
  f2(x + 1)
}
```

> The right hand side of this new version of f1 is now an implicit function value.
>   What’s the type of this value?
>   Previously, it was `Transaction => Int`, that is, the knowledge that the function has an implicit parameter got lost in the type.
>
> The main extension implemented by the pull request is to introduce implicit function types that mirror the implicit function values which we have already.
>   Concretely, the new type of f1 is:

```
implicit Transaction => Int
```

> Just like the normal function type syntax `A => B`, desugars to `scala.Function1[A, B]`, the implicit function type syntax `implicit A => B` desugars to `scala.ImplicitFunction1[A, B]`.
>   The same holds at other function arities. With [dotty’s pull request #1758](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/1758) merged, there is no longer an upper limit of 22 for such functions.